# What number is e+000?

Tags: c++, math

I have a data file full of numbers I'm loading into a vector of floats. However, the numbers in the data file are of the form `-4.60517025e+000` but are being read in like `-4.60517`

What number should `-4.60517025e+000` be?

Comment: Strange, because `10^000 = 1`.

Comment: @Radek S: That's the definition of raising to the power of 0. `A^0 = 1`. The maths professionals will be able to tell you if there are any limits on A.

Comment: @Martin what about `0^0`? My calculator gives a math error.

Comment: @Radek S: `0^0` is undefined by convention. The reason is that ideally you'd like the function `f(x) = x^0` to be continuous everywhere (just like `x^2` is), in which case it should be 1. But ideally you'd also like the function `g(x) = 0^x` to be continuous everywhere (just like `e^x` is), in which case it should be 0. Clearly it can't be both (and the 2-valued function `h(x,y) = x^y` must have a discontinuity), so the fix is to leave it undefined, and if you want to discuss a function that's the continuous extension of either f or g, you have to be explicit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The number -4.60517025e+000 is interpreted as -4.60517025 × 10<sup>0</sup> = -4.60517025.

More generally, a number of the form

```
AeB
```

is interpreted as A × 10<sup>B</sup>.

In your case, the file is being read properly, but the numbers are being rounded to some number of decimal points when being displayed. You can use stream manipulators to display them in their initial form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It might be useful to the OP to add a link to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation as well, just as more general background