# "e" in a bunch of numbers

Tags: java, variables, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What number is e+000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308112/what-number-is-e000)

Found `2.4397e6` in [Enum tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Result from printing that: `2439700.0`, what does the `e` mean? I don't think it's primitive data type though.

Comment: @ivanovic dude that's never been taught in school before I'm 15

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the exponent in scientific notation - so that value is 2.4397 x 10<sup>6</sup>.

See the [JLS section 3.10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) for precise details on floating point literals.

Answer (score 1):

"e" is a exponent in scientific notation .